# libGDX: 3d animation not working

Tags: java, animation, 3d, libgdx

I've created a .g3db animation file using Blender and fbxconv. Now, my libGDX project source code looks something like this:

```
public class test implements ApplicationListener {
// ...
 public ModelInstance fred
 public AnimationController animationController;

 public void create () {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    // ... 

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("data/fred.g3db", Model.class);
    loading = true;
 }

 private void doneLoading() {
    Model fredData = assets.get("data/fred.g3db", Model.class);

    fred = new ModelInstance(fredData);
    animationController = new AnimationController(fred);
    animationController.animate(fred.animations.get(0).id, -1, 1f, null, 0.2f);

    loading = false;
 }

 public void render () {
    if (loading && assets.update())
        doneLoading();
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(!loading) {
    animationController.update(10);
        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(fred,lights);
        modelBatch.end();
    }
 }

// [...] 
}
```

When I open this game, the model shows up perfectly, but there's no animation at all. I'm relatively new to libGDX game programming, so I have no ideas where I could have gone wrong. Any ideas?

(I don't know if this has something to do with anything, but when I converted the fbx file using fbxconv, I got several warnings, all looking like this:

```
WARNING: Node XXX uses RrSs mode, transformation might be incorrect.
```

But if what I read about this warning is true, it shouldn't actually cause any problems...)

Comment: Did you enable OpenGL ES2.0? Also have a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning. You should provide the delta value to animationController.update(). If you used blender to create the FBX file, you can safely ignore the RrSs warning.

Comment: Woah thanks, enabling OpenGL ES2.0 actually did the trick. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you enable OpenGL ES2.0? Also have a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning. You should provide the delta value to animationController.update(). If you used blender to create the FBX file, you can safely ignore the RrSs warning.

Comment: I am getting the same warnings, but my fbx-conv doesn't produce any files. I drag and drop myObject.fbx on fbx-conv-win32, but nothing happens. Everything works fine if i just export cube as fbx, but when it gets even a little more complicated nothing happens, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [here](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/),

> Don't drag and drop your fbx file on fbx-conv, it will not work for most scenarios.