# Libgdx 3d animation doesn't show correctly

Tags: animation, 3d, libgdx

I am new to 3D libgdx api, when I tried to run the animation, it shows a lot of randomly placed triangles on my screen, I followed this one, [libGDX: 3d animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959162/libgdx-3d-animation-not-working), when I play the animation in blender, it is okay. I exported it by default settings. I have placed all the .obj, .mtl, .fbx, all the textures, and I have read all the tutorials and comments of Mr.Awesome Xoppa, but still no result. Help will be much appreciated.

I have tried it on windows 7, OpenGL 2.0, intel GMA x3100, nightly builds of libgdx, even a simple knight animation in the gdx-test doesn't work, but the static meshes work fine. Today I tried it on linux, Mesa3D OpenGL 2.1, Ubuntu 12.04LTS, it works fine but there are some dark lines surrounding the animation. I think my archaic hardware and software support that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there is no way of running the animation in Windows 7, as it only supports OpenGL 2.0, but in Ubuntu it will work, as Mesa3D supports OpenGL 2.1. The black lines are the vertices that are not assigned to the bone.